# Python Counting words

Tags: python, count, range

I want to run a program in which it select every third letter out of a sentence (starting from the first letter), and print out those letters with spaces in between them. i am unable to work it out as it should run like this:

```
Message? pbaynatnahproarnsm
p y t h o n
```

and the code I am using it to work out is:

```
p = raw_input("Message? ")
count = 3
p.count()
print p
```

Can you please help me out with this thanks

Answer (score 7):

Grabbing every third letter is easy with [Python slice notation:](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html)

```
In [5]: x = 'pbaynatnahproarnsm'

In [6]: x[::3]
Out[6]: 'python'
```

You can then add a space in between each letter using [str.join](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
In [7]: ' '.join(x[::3])
Out[7]: 'p y t h o n'
```

Comment: actually I'm using python 2.6.5 so it is not not working in that one!! so what to do?

Comment: Try the code I posted in a Python interpreter. (It should work fine.) Then play around with it to see how it works. You should then be able to adapt it to your code.

Comment: @rocker789, also use ipython whenever you can, it rocks for pros and newbies alike.

Comment: actually I can't my computer can only afford to use this software could you please tell how to use in it please if you can so will be really appreciated. Thanks